# PHP configuration based on each domain user Not working when fastcgi apache server is running

Tags: php, linux, apache, httpd.conf, fpm

I have configured php configuration for each domain account like below in the file

```
/etc/sentora/configs/apache/phpconfig/domain_user.conf
```

That file i have made like below. For only the particular domain.

```
<Directory "/var/sentora/hostdata/domain_user/">
    php_value upload_max_filesize 512M
    php_value post_max_size 512M
    php_value max_execution_time 100
    php_value max_input_time 100
    php_value memory_limit 512M
    php_value file_uploads Off
</Directory>
```

Also I have configured below in the file **"/etc/sentora/configs/apache/httpd.conf"** correctly.

```
IncludeOptional /etc/sentora/configs/apache/phpconfig/*.conf
```

So it is working for me if i have changed my domain php version to 5.6, But its not working when I am checking after changed the php version to 7.0

It seems like when my server core php version is 5.6 its working on the version 5.6.

`php_value {key} {value}` was working when I used in mod_php but not in fastcgi

My phpinfo like below when its 7.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd0A5.jpg)

And when my domain is in php 5.6 my phpinfo look like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kstZa.jpg)

Can anyone help me to out from this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's how it works. The `php_value` Apache directive is provided by the `mod_php` Apache module. If you aren't using that module then you can't use the directive.

Comment: Thats correct only. It's working in `mod_php`, means working in php version 5.6. But we are trying to use in Apache php fastcgi, in which the php version is 7.0.

Comment: I'm not really sure of what you're trying to accomplish anyway. Are you trying to share the same configuration file between PHP/5.6 and 7.0? Otherwise, just configure 7.0 the way it's meant to (php.ini or .user.ini files).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/includefile/includefile.php
```

Then put your php_values in there

Comment: This question would be more appropriate at serverfault though.

Comment: php_value {key} {value} was working when I used in mod_php but not in fastcgi